# How to combine same files in mutliple folders into one file s3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

If I have a file in multiple folders in S3, how do I combine them together using boto3 python

Say in a bucket I have

```
bucket_a
   ts
     ts_folder
          a_date.csv
          b_date.csv
          c_date.csv
          d_date.csv

     ts_folder2
          a_date.csv
          b_date.csv
          c_date.csv
          d_date.csv
```

I need to combine these two files into one file, also ignoring header in second file

I am trying to figure out how to achieve using boto3 python or aws

Comment: Can you show us what you have already tried? Show the code where you read the files and use `boto3` to create the object on S3.

Comment: While it is possible to 'merge' S3 files by playing around with [UploadPartCopy - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_UploadPartCopy.html) to read in multiple files as source and copy them to the same destination file, this would not allow the files to be edited. Since you wish to remove the header from the second file, you will need to process the files through your Python script, as @JQadrad has recommended.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Also, [the files will have to be at least 5MB each](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/qfacts.html)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this. I assume you have your AWS credentials set up properly on your system. My suggestion would be to first add the lines of the CSV to a new variable. For the second CSV you will skip the first line. After finding all the lines you join them as a string so they can be written to an S3 object.

```py
import boto3
# Output will contain the CSV lines
output = []
with open("first.csv", "r") as fh:
    output.extend(fh.readlines())
with open("second.csv", "r") as fh:
    # Skip header
    output.extend(fh.readlines()[1:])

# Combine the lines as string
body = "".join(output)
# Create the S3 client (assuming credentials are setup)
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
# Write the object
s3_client.put_object(Bucket="my-bucket",
                     Key="combined.csv",
                     Body=body)
```

**Update**
This should help you with the S3 setup

```py
import boto3
session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='dev')
s3_client = session.client("s3")

bucket = "my-bucket"

files = []
for item in s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix="ts/")['Contents']:
    if item['Key'].endswith(".csv"):
        files.append(item['Key'])

output = []        
for file in files:
    body = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket,
                                Key=file)["Body"].read()
    output.append(body)

# Combine the lines as string
outputbody = "".join(output)
# Write the object
s3_client.put_object(Bucket=bucket,
                     Key="combined.csv",
                     Body=outputbody)
```

Comment: As the files are already in the s3 bucket, How can I achieve in combining all similar files under the "ts" folder . Important here is the number of folders inside "ts" can be only one or more depending on the number of files in the sftp

Comment: @Kar, take a look at the update. That should get you started I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I will try up with that logic

Comment: Can you please check this s3_hook 
 I am confused which function actually gets all the objects like you did https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/airflow/hooks/S3_hook.html

Comment: In your code its good for one file inside the folder , I have multiple different files in each folder ... I have updated the original path structure

Comment: Did you try to run my code? The bucket should be `bucket_a` and the prefix should be `ts`, so it will find CSVs in both the subfolders inside `ts`. 

I am not familiar with Airflow, but an S3 URL normally looks like `s3://{bucket}{key}`, so for example `s3://bucket_a/ts/ts_folder/a_data.csv".